# how to make url as pretty url in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

I am new to ci. naybody knows how to minify the url.
for example : yourdmain.com/blog/view/blog-title
I need this url to be like this  : yourdmain.com/blog-title 
please explain how to do this 
this can be many like blog, categories, pages, posts 
please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use route.php under your config folder

```
 $route['blog-title] = 'blog/view/blog-title';
```

if you need dynamically loading based on a title

```
  $route['(:any)/index.html'] = 'blog/view/$1';

   // will route any url with /index.html to your controller

 $route['(:any).html'] = 'blog/view/$1';

 // will route any url with title.html to your controller then pass your title as your function variable
```

Why index.html or .html

This is my way i use to distinguish my other urls to my blog titles urls .. meaning only urls with extension index.html or .html will be routed to my blog/view path

Comment: thank for your reply what is index.html is this applicable for all controllers like post/view/$1, category/view/$1,pages/view/$1 please explain i dont know how to do this

Comment: I have edited my answer .. explaining why use index.html or .html

Comment: Roby i got it. its ok for blog case. can i use this for post, pages, categories. can i use this for these things. this is my doubt

Comment: U can add them to your config/route , then in your controller check your url segment and if its a post then do what you want to do with the post , same goes with pages and categories

Comment: $route['(:any).html'] = 'blog/view/$1';
$route['(:any).html'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['(:any).html'] = 'category/view/$1';
$route['(:any).html'] = 'post/view/$1';

is it correct , is this works if do like this

Comment: No , $route['page/(:any).html'] = 'blog/view/$1' in view check your url segment if $this->uri->segment(1) == 'page'; do something for a page and a reference passed variable, same goes with categories in your route and controller function

Answer (score 0):

You can have hyphens instead of underbars putting these lines in the file `routes.php`

```
$route['(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)'] = "$1_$2_$3_$4_$5";

$route['(.+)-(.+)-(.+)-(.+)'] = "$1_$2_$3_$4";

$route['(.+)-(.+)-(.+)'] = "$1_$2_$3";

$route['(.+)-(.+)'] = "$1_$2";
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: @tsnorri
I know, but it was very useful for my and i think it will help her. In CI3 there are the next options

`| $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
|
| This is not exactly a route, but allows you to automatically route

| controller and method names that contain dashes. '-' isn't a valid
| class or method name character, so it requires translation.
| When you set this option to TRUE, it will replace ALL dashes in the
| controller and method URI segments.`